# What is assembly interning?

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly

What is assembly interning? For what purpose it is used for?
I heard that it is a new feature added by ASP.Net 4.5. 
Can anyone please explain this feature. Is it same as String interning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From book  Developing Windows Azure and Web Services:

> ASP.NET has a feature called shadow copying that enables assemblies that are used in
>   an application domain to be updated without unloading the AppDomain. Normally, this is
>   required because the Common Language Runtime (CLR) will lock the assemblies so you can’t
>   just copy a new assembly over it. Shadow copying means that the original assembly is copied
>   to a temporary location. The copied assembly is locked, and the original assembly can be
>   updated with a new version.
>
> ASP.NET 4.5 adds a new feature called assembly interning. Because all DLLs are already
>   located in one location (the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder), interning analyzes this folder
>   for duplicate assemblies. Those assemblies are then moved to a special location, and all the
>   original references are replaced with what’s called a symbolic link.

Comment: 100% copied from the book 'Developing Windows Azure and Web Services'.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh882452.aspx):

> **ASP.NET**
>
> Bin assemblies interning (sharing common assemblies): The ASP.NET
> shadow copy feature enables assemblies that are used in an application
> domain to be updated without unloading that AppDomain (necessary
> because the CLR locks assemblies that are being used). This is done by
> copying application assemblies to a separate location (either a
> default CLR-determined location or a user-specified one) and loading
> the assemblies from that location. This allows the original assembly
> to be updated while the shadow copy is locked. ASP.NET turns on this
> feature by default for Bin folder assemblies so that DLLs can continue
> to be updated while a site is up and running.

Also check

- [Look at Sharing Common Assemblies in ASP.NET 4.5](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sateesh-arveti/archive/2011/11/30/look-at-sharing-common-assemblies-in-asp-net-4-5.aspx)
- [What's new in ASP.NET? (Sharing Common Assemblies)](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc_perf_3)